# Passing a function pointer as parameter to fopen

Tags: c

I created a small C program for creating a time stamp and append it to a file text name:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void time_stamp(){
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer [80];
    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    strftime (buffer,80,"myFile_%F.txt",timeinfo);
    printf ("%s", buffer);
}


int main ()
{
    void (*filename_ptr)();
    filename_ptr = &time_stamp;

    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen (filename_ptr, "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2017);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

But I can't get fopen to accept the pointer to the function creating the name with the time stamp. It is expecting a const char. How can i cast my function pointer to it?

Comment: What  do you expect fopen to do with the function pointer?

Comment: It's because your CPU doesn't have the DWIM (Do What I Mean) instruction. Until then you need to actually tell the computer what to do because it can't read your mind.

Comment: Check your manual or manpage for the prototype of `fopen`. That is the contract you need to fulfil. These are the rules you have to obey. If there is a `const char *` as first parameter, YOU SHALL NOT PASS some weird fancy function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, but you can just call the function through the pointer appending `()`. For this to work, change your function to actually return `const char *` (or `char *`)

Note you can't just return a pointer to your `buffer` because this is a local variable that is no longer existent when the function returns. You could pass a pointer to `buffer` from outside the function. Your prototype then should be

```
char *time_stamp(char *buf, size_t len);
```

**modified code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *time_stamp(char *buf, size_t len){
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    strftime (buf,len,"myFile_%F.txt",timeinfo);
    return buf;
}


int main ()
{
    char *(*filename_ptr)(char *, size_t);
    filename_ptr = &time_stamp;
    char buffer[80];

    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen (filename_ptr(buffer, 80), "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2017);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

---

There are other alternatives how to design this function. [Neroku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8012646/neroku)'s answer is good when you are sure you never need the function in a threaded context. It simplifies the usage and there are even some standard C library functions designed in that way.

The third way would be to make the buffer an *allocated object* by obtaining it from `malloc()`. This has the advantage of being thread-safe and not needing any extra arguments, the function itself controls the size of the buffer like in your original broken version. The disadvantage is that the *caller* must `free()` the memory when done with it. Example code for this (I don't recommend it here):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *time_stamp(){
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

    char *buf = malloc(80);
    strftime (buf,80,"myFile_%F.txt",timeinfo);
    return buf;
}


int main ()
{
    char *(*filename_ptr)();
    filename_ptr = &time_stamp;

    FILE * fp;

    char *filename = filename_ptr();
    fp = fopen (filename, "w+");
    free(filename);
    fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2017);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`fopen()` expects a `const char *` as the first argument:

```
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
```

In your function `time_stamp()` you are **printing**  the timestamp and returning nothing, i.e.: `void`.

---

Your new `time_stamp()` function could be instead (note the `static` at the declaration of `buffer`):

```
const char* time_stamp(){
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm * timeinfo;
   static char buffer [80];
   time (&rawtime);
   timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

   strftime (buffer,80,"myFile_%F.txt",timeinfo);
   return buffer;
}
```

You could then **call** this new function at the moment of calling `fopen()`. The value returned by `time_stamp()` will turn into the first argument of `fopen()`:

```
const char * (*filename_ptr)();
filename_ptr = &time_stamp;
// ...
fp = fopen (filename_ptr(), "w+");
```

Note that the type of the value returned from `time_stamp()` matches now the type of the first argument that `fopen()` expects (i.e.: `const char *`).

---

## Note on thread-safety

Since the function `time_stamp()` contains *statically allocated storage* (`buffer`), it is unsafe to use this function in a multi-threading program, since all the threads *that call this function* will be sharing a single instance of this storage.

Comment: Not that it's relevant to the OP, but the `static` makes the function thread unsafe. Just to keep in mind ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes, the code above is *thread unsafe*, but I am not striving for *thread safe* code.

Comment: In order to improve clarity of your answer and partially reduce risks with reusing it for similar future purposes, I recommed to edit that slightly risky assumption into the answer and explain in which way and in which circumstances the function needs to be used in order to be safe. Generally however, writing a threadsage function is preferrable to writing functions which can be used in a certain way inspite of being unsafe.